# How to generate a 2D-array from a 1D-array using map and filter?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, higher-order-functions

I have the desired output using a loop today but how can I exchange this loop with a one line expression using map and filter?

I start with an array of countries. From this one I generate a second array with the initial letters using map. I would now like to build a 2D-array that contains all the countries with the same initial letter in separate arrays using map and filter so that I can get rid of the loop I use today.

```
let countries = ["Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Canada"]

var initials = Set(countries.map { $0.prefix(1) }).sorted()

func countriesByInitial() -> [[String]] {
    var result = [[String]]()
    for initial in initials {
        result.append(countries.filter { $0.prefix(1) == initial })
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: post your code, not a screenshot...

Comment: Copy/paste code, not screenshot.

Comment: Here is a real world example of why you should really post code instead of image: in addition to I will need to copy/paste your code, for some reason I am connected to a network that makes accessing to the i.stack.imgur.com images is blocked! therefore I can't even review the code.

Comment: OK, I've posted the code now.

Comment: Is your array always sorted?

Comment: Yes, the array is already sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Swift 4 method `reduce(into:)` if your array it is already sorted, otherwise you just need to sort it before grouping it:

```
let countries = ["Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Canada"]

let grouped: [[String]] = countries.reduce(into: []) {
    if $0.last?.last?.prefix(1) == $1.prefix(1) {
        $0[$0.index(before: $0.endIndex)].append($1)
    } else {
        $0.append([$1])
    }
}

print(grouped)   // [["Albania", "Algeria", "Angola"], ["Bahamas", "Bahrain"], ["Canada"]]\n"
```

Comment: countries.reduce(into: [["0"]]){(result: inout [[String]], string: String)  in
            _ = result.last!.last!.first! != string.first! ?  result.append([string]) : result[result.endIndex - 1].append(string)
            }.dropFirst()

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve it by **group > sort > map** combination as:

```
let countries = ["Algeria", "Albania", "Belarus", "Bahamas", "Canada"]
let groupedDict = Dictionary(grouping: countries, by: { $0.prefix(1) })
let sortedDict = groupedDict.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
let arr2D = sortedDict.map({ $0.value })
```

You can write it in a single line:

```
let arr = (Dictionary(grouping: countries, by: { $0.prefix(1) })).sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }).map({ $0.value })
```

---

**You can use reduce on array as well:**

**// $0 will be of type `[[String]]`**

**// $1 will be of type `String`**

```
let arr2D: [[String]] = countries.reduce(into: []) {
    let checkChar = $1.first
    if let idx = $0.index(where: {$0.first?.first == checkChar }) {
        $0[idx].append($1)
    } else {
        $0.append([$1])
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr2D` is an array. What is your required output?

Comment: @DiezNobach read the answer properly. It gives a 2D array like you want. Nice answer btw Ankit. _clap_ _clap_

Comment: Thanks for point it out @MartinR, I forgot to change variable name from what I tried on playground. Updated the answer now.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. I'm looking for a way to do it directly on the arrays without having to go through a dictionary conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You could *map* the `initial` set by *filtering* `countries` strings' first letter as:

```
let countries = ["Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Canada"]
var initials = Set(countries.map { $0.prefix(1) }).sorted()

let array = initials.map { letter -> [String] in
    return countries.filter { $0.prefix(1) == letter }
}
```

therefore, `array` is an array of arrays of strings (`[[String]]`), as:

> [["Albania", "Algeria", "Angola"], ["Bahamas", "Bahrain"], ["Canada"]]

Comment: This would execute a filter for every initial

Comment: This is not effective solution of the problem, too much unneeded looping.